# Are there any coherent, complete, mathematical systems that do not imply the existence of the infinite?

Tags: real-analysis, meta-math

Basically, are there any systems(complete with axioms) that do not imply the existence of an infinity? Is it possible to construct a mathematical system without infinity?

Comment: Sure, the theory of a particular finite structure would be an example: the theory of the integers mod 5, say. But if you mean a system adequate for all of mathematics, or at least a large part of it, then I for one can't think of any.

Comment: This is pretty vague.  You tagged the question "real-analysis", do you mean is there a construction of the reals that doesn't have an "infinite" property?  Or do you mean is there a set of axioms with only a finite number of theorems following?  What is "complete"?  Do you want to be able to discuss asymptotic behavior without axioms using a symbol for infinity?

Comment: It is probably worth mentioning that a huge amount of model theory is devoted to studying and proving theories about large finite structures, like the states that a microprocessor can be in.  Entire logic devoted to the "finite" universe, mostly dedicated to compressing it into a tractable state that can be checked by enumeration.

Answer (score 4):

First-order theory of (lots of [things there is a first-order theory of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_first-order_theories)), if it's complete (I'm assuming you mean [complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_theory) in the sense of mathematical logic) and doesn't have a predicate "is infinite".   [Real closed fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field), for example.

Just to clarify: any model of the theory of real closed fields is infinite, and for any positive integer $n$ there is a theorem that says the field $F$ has at least $n$ distinct elements, but the statement "$F$ is infinite" is not part of the theory.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the axioms of [ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) and replace the [Axiom of Infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_infinity) with its negation, you get the [hereditarily finite sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditarily_finite_set). This is a consistent set theory in which you can model each of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ... But there is no set containing all of them.

In fact it's precisely the Axiom of Infinity (in standard math) that allows us to form the completed set of natural numbers. Without a special axiom, we can't do it.

The reason most mathematicians accept the Axiom of Infinity is for convenience. It's hard to do math without infinite sets.

The question as to whether the Axiom of Infinity is true or false in some Platonic sense is a matter of philosophy. In fact the Axiom of Infinity is exactly what gives us an [actual infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actual_infinity) in the sense of Aristotle.

In math we are free to take axioms for convenience. Since it's far easier (and way more fun) to do math with infinite sets, that's the choice that's made.